# FF sporadic failure to load web font hosted on s3

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, amazon-s3, webfonts

We have a font hosted on S3 as a woff and referenced via CSS.  The S3 bucket has CORS configured to allow cross-site access from anywhere.  Normally, the font displays with no issues.  Sometimes, however, Firefox fails to render the font and the error console reports "bad URI or cross-site access not allowed".  I'm trying, without much success, to figure out exactly what sequence of HTTP calls FF uses to obtain the font resource from S3 so I can debug the situation with curl.  Thus far, debugging with

`curl -s -I -X OPTIONS --header "Origin: http://www.foo.com" --header "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" s3.amazonaws.com/font.woff`

has yielded only HTTP 200 responses, i.e. provides no information about what might be failing.  I'm kind of at a loss as to how to figure out what's going on.  I don't know whether S3 is sporadically returning spurious 403 responses to the OPTIONS requests, 403 responses to the requests for the resource itself, or our HTML/CSS is somehow subtly broken and/or exposing a bug in FF.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try debugging using the Firebug extension for Firefox. It is very powerful, and will show you all network requests, including headers.

Comment: Sadly, the sporadic nature of the bug has so far resisted attempts to reproduce it with something like Firebug open, but hopefully that'll change soon.

Comment: Finally duplicated it with Firebug, and it really looks like FF is just flat not requesting the font resource.  Maybe some kind of super bizarre timing issue...

Comment: Weird. I came to think of two things:
 1. You could use Wireshark to look at the raw network traffic
 2. Are you doing any sort of load balancing using CloudFront?

Comment: Yeah, Wireshark hasn't been super helpful either - best I can get is that Firefox doesn't request the font resource at all when it doesn't work.  Probably some weirdness with the CSS and/or Firefox, but I haven't been able to make sense of it.  And no, we aren't using CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an intentional preventative measure against xss (cross site scripting) attacks that firefox has implemented.

Read about one possible solution here: [Downloadable font on firefox: bad URI or cross-site access not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024333/downloadable-font-on-firefox-bad-uri-or-cross-site-access-not-allowed)