# Downloadable font on firefox: bad URI or cross-site access not allowed

Tags: css, amazon-s3, cross-domain, font-face, gecko

I'm a webmaster at http://www.beperk.com (I'm giving you the URL so you are able to check the problem) and I'm having lots of problems using @font-face in CSS.

I want to use the foundicons from zurb dot com so I hosted them at Amazon S3.

I set up the bucket to allow crossdomain access as specified here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors

And everything started to work seamless at webkit, trident and gecko... mostly: when browsing the web with firefox (version 17, 18 and 19 tested) all the icons fails randomly with this error:

```
Timestamp: 22/02/13 13:18:01
Error: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "GeneralFoundicons" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
```

And I say randomly since after a full reload of the page (with control/command + R) every single icon appears normally to fail again after some visits.

Can anyone find the problem?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

On your server you will need to add:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

To the header of the font files, so for example if you are using Apache you can add this to the .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I'm using a CDN to serve my files and have added this header to the origin webserver. The CDN is configured to use the same headers as the origin and indeed "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" is in the headers of both when I pull the file using "curl -I". And yet...Firefox still won't load those font files.

Comment: The CDN would need to support `Origin: Vary` for this to work. Unfortunately CloudFront doesn't — if that's what you're using (you didn't say).

Comment: Originally he was using S3, so just general storage for these files, which as we know isn't really a CDN - and tends to be slower. Is there a workaround for CloudFront?

Comment: Add to *woff2*: `<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks alot.
I have a WordPress site on my domain.
I added .htaccess file containing above code in the same folder where my font files are present.

Comment: I had to add mod_headers to my apache: `sudo a2enmod headers` + restart apache

Answer (score 17):

If anyone are using local resource and facing this problem in firefox. You can go to `about:config` and change the `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` preference to `false`.

see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs

Comment: Splendid!  Instantly solved what seemed like a massively weird Webfonts problem within what is currently a local development experiment, which was not an issue of any sort with Chrome, IE or Opera.

Answer (score 9):

try to use implemented base64-encoded fonts like:

```
@font-face {
 font-family:"font-name";
 src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,[paste-64-code-here]);
 font-style:normal;
 font-weight:400;
}
```

see: http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri

it worked perfectly.

Comment: here is my code, how to integrate `@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Roboto Thin'), local('Roboto-Thin'), url(fonts/roboto/gwVJDERN2Amz39wrSoZ7FxTbgVql8nDJpwnrE27mub0.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}`

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem in Firefox (local resource access problem) using url: `src: url("../fuentes/EurostileLTStd.otf");` instead of `src: uri("../fuentes/EurostileLTStd.otf");`.

Comment: Waht is this bro ?!

Comment: I meant `src: url(...)` instead of `src: uri(...)`. I've misspelled, sorry.