# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons are not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I downloaded bootstrap 3.0 and can't get the glyphicons to work. I get some kind of "E003" error. Any ideas why this is happening? I tried both locally and online and I still get the same problem.

Comment: where are you getting the error?

Comment: Anywhere I insert the icons...

Here is the error I get. Only thing I did is to download bootstrap from the site customizer, and replaced the previous files (font files had different names though). Now they aren't working...

Have also tried several browsers, firefox, chrome, ie, same thing...

http://i.imgur.com/2f474kX.jpg

Comment: I have just downloaded the latest release today and the glyphs do not show if I use the minimized CSS file. If I use the 'normal' bootstrap.css everything works fine.

Comment: As of June 23, 2015, include the latest release v3.3.5 maxcdn you have no errors

Comment: I found that I was using the glyphicons on a white background and expecting them to show up. Using <i style="color:black" class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></i> fixed it.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error and your code.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate a [mcve] and the exact errors you get from it (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was looking through this old question of mine and since what was supposed to be the correct answer up until now, was given by me in the comments, I think I also deserve the credit for it.

The problem lied in the fact that the **glyphicon font files downloaded from bootstrap's customizer tool were not the same with the ones that are downloaded from the redirection found at bootstrap's homepage.** The ones that are working as they should are the ones that can be downloaded from the following link:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download
```

Anyone having problems with old bad customizer files should overwrite the fonts from the link above.

Comment: The Customizer problem was fixed a long time ago. It's no longer an issue in current Bootstrap.

Comment: Nowadays, they're probably running into icon font location issues instead, [even though the way the icon font paths work is documented](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use)...

Comment: there are certain things to check out for this issue. - 

Check this mime types in IIS for your site.. It must be there for one of the above issues...

- `application/vnd.ms-fontobject` - .eot
- `application/x-font-woff` - .woff
- `application/x-font-ttf` - .ttf
- `image/svg+xml` - .svg

Comment: My glyphicons work in all browsers except IE. IE displays them on first load - hit F5 and then no longer displays. The DOM is correct, the css applied is correct. I cannot find a solution. Ideas?

Comment: I can check/uncheck the "content: "\e080"" CSS that sets the content to a particular character. When I do that, the span's size physically changes from something to nothing and back. So it really feels like IE bug - failing to draw the character.

Answer (score 480):

I was having the same issue and couldn't find any information about it except in the hidden comments on this page.  My font files were loading just fine according to Chrome, but the icons weren't displaying properly.  I'm making this an answer so it will hopefully help others.

Something was wrong with the font files that I downloaded from Bootstrap 3's customizer tool.  To get the correct fonts, go to the [Bootstrap homepage](http://getbootstrap.com/) and download the full .zip file.  Extract the four font files from there to your fonts directory and everything should work.

Comment: Should be fixed very soon, if not already. The Bootstrap team is aware of the problem. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9925. Bootstrap recently updated their Glyphicons to include new icons and I believe they forgot to update their customizer files.

Comment: swapping the fonts files for the ones included in bootstrap-3.0.0 of the getbootstrap.com home page works. thanks for the tip!

Comment: I had a slightly different problem where I was using project.less in the "bootstrap-master" directory to @import all other LESS files  

**THE FIX**  
After Inspecting the broken icon element in Safari, and viewing the Logs (lat icon in Inspector's left column) I noticed the fonts were trying to be loaded from the root directory of my site, causing a 404 error.  
  

After downloading new fonts and changing "@icon-font-path:" from "../fonts/"; to "fonts/"; I was good to go.  
  
The problem was that I was loading project.less & importing all other .LESS files in the bootstrap-master directory.

Comment: Correct answer! Font files from customizer are corrupted!

Comment: Thumbs up - this is the correct answer ! I think the problem is related to the fact that the files in the compiled version are not well encrypted.

Comment: Wait... Then are you going to ask the users of your website to download these fonts and put them into their fonts directory?!

Comment: @Aidin No. Their browsers will download them automatically. Just like the browsers automatically download CSS, JS, and other files.

Comment: `glyphicons` are not working in `bootstrap` installed by `bower`, but works good installed from zip downloaded from official bootstrap site

Comment: Yes it is font problem. to avoid it use link to CDN resource. like <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: i using glyphicons from a cdn, but still i get only squares @AymanAl-Absi

Comment: @jeff this did not work for me. Before it works well locally, but wne the webapp is access online, it dosent show up. then when i applied your solution, it was still the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: I simply gave up using their icons. No matter what I do where I download them from, they just don't work. So... seems I will just be using FontAwesome instead!

Comment: I wanted to add my "me too" response and say that after wasting a couple of hours of effort, and almost rage quitting my career, I found this answer and now I have working glyphicons again. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you!!  I had generated my bootstrap project through compass and had the same issue.

Comment: I can't wait to be part of all the people who succeeded but right now despite having tried almost every single solution and answer of the Stack,  I'm still unable to see the icons.  I even tried to start a completely new MVC 5 app and using Nuget to install bootstrap latest version 3.3.7 which install all the folders correctly and nothing shows a 404 in the browser debugger tool or anything telling me that the fonts aren't loaded and I can tell you that the code for the span is perfect so where is my problem.  I honestly don't know.  I tested all the browsers and none shows the icons

Answer (score 241):

Note to readers: be sure to read [@user2261073's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working/18369117#comment26972465_18369117) and [@Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474869/247702) concerning a bug in the customizer. It's likely the cause of your problem.

---

The font file isn't being loaded correctly. Check if the files are in their expected location.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

As indicated by Daniel, it might also be a mimetype issue. Chrome's dev tools show downloaded fonts in the network tab:

[image: chrome network tab font download]

Comment: and that the mimetypes are registered properly.

Comment: ...although the files should be in place when I downloaded the bootstrap.zip file, I still double-checked and everythins is in place. How do I check the mimetypes registration (=?)

Comment: chrome indicates that svg, ttf and woff are loaded but not eot. :/ Can anyone point me somewhere for what to look at?

Comment: @user2261073 the *.eot*  file shouldn't load, unless you're using Internet Explorer.

Comment: now I know for certain that the .eot is not loading. question is why not? path is correct.

Comment: I see, so if everything else is loaded properly, why won't they show? Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2261073 Did you check the mimetype? See the screenshot, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's loading properly, check link: http://i.imgur.com/eFkVgek.jpg the icons are those rectangles

Comment: Looks like I found the problem. The bootstrap customizer seems to be sending different sized fonts than the ones that are inside the whole bootstrap package that comes with the examples. I replaced the files and everything is working fine now. It's most likely a bug in bootstrap's customizer? Who knows. Can I report this somewhere so they can look into it?

Comment: @user2261073 You can report it on the GitHub project. There already seems to be an active bug report: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10008

Comment: @Jeff solved my problem below.  Useful discussion on font MIME types http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts

Comment: Thanks for the "Note to readers:" pointing to Jeff's answer. +1 for putting it about your answer.

Comment: To determine if this is your issue, open the bootstrap.css file and search for ``glyphicon``.  If the path to it is ``../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`` then your css is ok.  In my case it said ``../../../../../Downloads/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot``

Comment: If I have status code 206 (Partial Content), is it OK?

Comment: @zygimantus I didn't know browsers request fonts in chunks, but as long as it loads fine, it's OK. If your font doesn't load fine, you might want to open a new question with further details of your situation.

Comment: Removing url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff') from src did the trick for me.

Answer (score 77):

In my case I was getting a 404 for ***glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff***, and non visible glyphicons on mobile browsers.

Looks like there is some confusion about the MIME type for woff, more than one MIME type being accepted by different browsers, but the [W3C says](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b):

```
application/font-woff
```

Edit: After testing the following MIME type for woff works on all browsers currently:

```
application/x-font-woff
```

Edit: Latest version of Bootstrap at this time (3.3.5) uses .woff2 fonts with the same initial result as .woff, the W3C still [defining the spec](http://dev.w3.org/webfonts/WOFF2/spec/) but at the moment the MIME type seems to be:

```
application/font-woff2
```

Comment: This pointed me in the good direction but it also gave me another warning in Chrome... The MIME type should be in fact: `application/x-font-woff` then Firefox and Chrome were finally both happy :)

Comment: Thanks, that was the real problem for me. Everything was working OK locally but once published to Azure the .woff type was the only one giving problems.

Answer (score 59):

**-If you followed the highest rated answer and it's still not working**:

The `Font` folder **MUST** be on the same level as your CSS folder.  Fixing the path in `bootstrap.css` **will not** work.

`Bootstrap.css` has to navigate to the `Fonts` folder *exactly* like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: I think 70% of Glyphicon not working in of this case, great answears, I often put Bootstrap css files in css/bootstrap. Just move them up to css and everything work

Comment: Well the path for me looks EXACTLY as prescribed by you but it still doesn't work for me. Neither does downloading the source package and replacing the font files. I must add that some glyphicons load while others don’t. Can you help?

Comment: where is the font folder i don't have ?

Comment: Also the `css` folder has to be a subfolder of the folder containing your HTML file. So at a minimum, you have to have 1) your HTML file, 2) a css file in a subfolder called `css`, and 3) the font files in a subfolder called `fonts`.

Comment: This makes no difference when loading from CDN; only when loading locally.  Adding a link to `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css` solved it for me.

Comment: In the end adding the link I posted did not completely work, because newer versions of v3 have more icons. In the end I downloaded them from the source (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.4.1) and put them in the proper place (as mentioned in this answer). There is an additional `.woff2` file you may need to add however.

Answer (score 55):

If the other solutions aren't working, you may want to try importing Glyphicons from an external source, rather than relying on Bootstrap to do everything for you. To do this:

You can either do this in HTML:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or CSS:

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css")
```

Credit to edsiofi from this thread: [Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222849/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-cdn)

Answer (score 35):

In case someone else ended up here and using Bootstrap >= v4.0: **glyphicon support is dropped**

The relevant part from the release notes:

> Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:
>
> the upstream version of [Glyphicons](https://glyphicons.com/)
>
> [Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/)
>
> [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Source: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components

If you want to use glyphicons you need to download it separately.

I personally tried Font Awesome and it is quite good. Adding icons is similar to glypicon way:

```
<i class="fas fa-chess"></i>
```

Answer (score 19):

You can add this line of code and done.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is missing many of the newer icons added in later versions of v3.

Comment: Perfect answer, for me anyway.

Answer (score 18):

Azure Websites are missing *woff* MIME configuration. You must add following entry into web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `woff, woff2 and ttf` extensions ?

Answer (score 16):

As @Stijn described, the default location in `Bootstrap.css` is incorrect when installing this package from `Nuget`.

Change this section to look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- opentype'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: If you're using LESS you can just override it in your less file and change the URL's to match relative paths from your gen'd CSS file or root them.

Comment: This should no longer be an issue with the latest release of bootstrap. Update!

Answer (score 8):

IIS will not server `.woff` files by default, so in IIS you'll need to add a `<mimeMap>` entry to your `web.config` file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This scales a lot better instead of having to remember to configure this for each IIS machine.  Nice mention

Comment: You should update your mimetype to be "application/font-woff" as per current standards: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142316/2267817

Comment: ***application/font-woff vs application/x-woff*** ?

Answer (score 7):

Do you have all below files in your fonts directory

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. A person can find the right folder to place these files, using Xenu's link sleuth: http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

Comment: But, there are people who have all these files in the fonts folder but are still getting this error if mime type woff is not registered with IIS.

Comment: fonts directory is required ? I have only **bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js**

Answer (score 7):

I modified my less variables.less file 
I modified the variable

```
@icon-font-path:          "fonts/";
```

the original was

```
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
```

It was causing a problem

Comment: For bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.1 gem it seems to need `$icon-font-path: "/assets/bootstrap/"`.

Comment: Definitely the way to work WITH bootstrap and not against it.

Answer (score 6):

This was the reason, why the icons didn't show up for me:

```
* {
    arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

After i have removed this part of my `CSS`, everything worked like it should. The !important was the one causing trouble.

Comment: Thank you! After scratching my head for over 4 hours and trying numerous different things I remembered that I added a font on "span" with important.
Removed it and everything is back to normal..

Answer (score 5):

This is due to wrong coding in bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css. When you download Bootstrap 3.0 from the Customizer the following code is missing:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Since this is the main code for using Glyphicons, it won't work ofc...

Download the css-files from the full package and this code will be implemented.

Answer (score 5):

Another problem/solution may be having this Bootstrap 2.x code:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
```

and when migrating based on the [guide](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration-classes) (`.icon-*   ---> .glyphicon .glyphicon-*`):

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

you forget to add the icon class (containing the font reference):

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is what fixed it for me. I was getting "bad URI" error using in Firebug console. The icons were showing up as E### numbers. I had to add a .htaccess file in my 'fonts' directory.

`<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>`

Possible duplicate of: [Downloadable font on firefox: bad URI or cross-site access not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024333/downloadable-font-on-firefox-bad-uri-or-cross-site-access-not-allowed/15025681#15025681)

Answer (score 5):

This is very much a long shoot, but it was my case and since it is not here already.

If you are compiling Twitter Bootstrap from SASS using `gulp-sass` or `grunt-sass` ie. `node-sass`. Make sure your node modules are up to date, especially if your are working on a rather old project.

It turns out that as of some time back the SASS directive `@at-root` is used in the definition of the `@font-face` in glyphicons, see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/b01ab4942233bd7316a0634472e1243b13fb9f46/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss.

The gotcha here is that `node-sass` ie. `libsass` do not support the `@at-root` directive if it is too old. If this is the case you will get a `@font-face` wrapped in a `@at-root` which the browser have no idea what to do with. The result of this is that no font will be downloaded and you will likely see garbage instead of icons.

Answer (score 4):

Note: below is likely a niche scenario, but I wanted to share it in case someone else might find it useful.

In a rails project, we are reusing quite a bit through a gem that is a Rails engine using `bootstrap-sass`.  All was well in the main project with the exception of the glyphicon font path resolution.

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404 (Not Found)
```

We found that `$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper` was `false` during the resolution when we expected it to be true, so the path was different.

We caused the `$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper` to be initialized in the engine gem by doing:

```
// explicit sprockets import to get glyphicon font paths correct
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import "bootstrap/variables";
```

e.g. this caused the path to resolve to:

```
/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Again, this shouldn't be necessary in any normal rails project using `bootstrap-sass`, we just happen to be reusing a lot of views and this worked out for us.  Hopefully this can assist someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what official documentation says regarding fonts not rendering.

> Changing the icon font location
> Bootstrap assumes icon font files will be located in the ../fonts/ directory, relative to the compiled CSS files. Moving or renaming those font files means updating the CSS in one of three ways:
>
> Change the @icon-font-path and/or @icon-font-name variables in the source Less files.
> Utilize the relative URLs option provided by the Less compiler.
> Change the url() paths in the compiled CSS.
> Use whatever option best suits your specific development setup.

Other than that it could be that you missed to copy the **fonts folder to the root directory**

Comment: I have missed to copy the font folder i don't know where is it ?can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it was caused by the variables.less file. Overriding it to set the icon-font-path value solved the problem.

The file structured looks like this:

```
\Content
        \Bootstrap
        \Fonts
 styles.less
 variables.less
```

Adding my own variables.less file in the root of Content and referencing this in styles.less resolved the 404 error.

Variables.less contains:

```
@icon-font-path:          "fonts/";
```

Comment: This helped me realise I nuked my path variable... random but yeah thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got Bootstrap from NuGet. When I published my site the glyphs didn't work.

In my case I got it working by setting the Build Action for each of the font files to 'Content' and set them to 'Copy Always'.

Answer (score 3):

i had a box width code \e094 for glyphicon-arrow-down, in fact i solved the problem adding **glyphicon** in css class like that :

```
<i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
```

if it could help someone ...

Comment: Dude this was my problem too using the CDN

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you aren't over specifying the font family, for example

```
*{font-family: Verdana;}
```

will remove the halflings font from i elements.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem where the browser was unable to find the font files, and my issue was due to exclusions in my .htaccess file that was whitelisting files that shouldn't be sent to `index.php` for processing. As the font file couldn't be loaded the characters were replaced with BLOB.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|css|js|ico|rss|xml|json)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

As you can see, files like images, rss, and xml are excluded from the rewrite, but the font files are `.woff` and `.woff2` files, so these also needed adding to the whitelist.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|css|js|ico|rss|xml|json|woff|woff2)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Adding `woff` and `woff2` to the whitelist allows the font files to be loaded, and the glyphicons should then display properly.

Answer (score 2):

You must to set by this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<style type="text/css"> 
     @font-face {   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';   
     src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');   
     src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),  
     url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
     url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg'); } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was replacing routes from:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

to

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you include the icon in bootstrap 3

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>
```

http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
      src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')         format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');}
```

I am using bootstrap with namespace and glyphicons not working but after adding above line in code glyphicons working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just renamed the font from bootstrap.css using Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You must to set by this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),       url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),        url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),       url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` and not `glyphiconshalflings-regular.woff`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for anyone using Nancy (NancyFx).

I have an ASP.NET-hosted NancyFX app, and I obtained Boostrap via NuGet.

My glyphicons were not working, but it turned out not to be an issue of bad font files, incorrect CSS relative directory paths, or any of the other things mentioned in the other answers.

The problem was that I was missing a convention, telling Nancy where to look for content. Once I realized that, the solution was simply to add the following overload to my bootstrapper file:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
{
    base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
    nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
        StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/fonts"));
    nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
        StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/Scripts"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a CDN for the bootstrap CSS files it may be the culprit, as the glyph files (e.g. *glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff*) are taken from the CDN as well.

In my case, I faced this issue using Microsoft's CDN, but switching to [MaxCDN](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css) resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when using a web fragment in Eclipse. The font files were corrupted when packed in to the web fragment jar. 
Copying the font files to the project where the fragment was used solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers works for me....

The problem was that I was trying `<span class="icones glyphicon glyphicon-pen">`
and after one hour I realized that this icon **was not included in the Bootstrap pack**! While the envelope icon was working fine..

Comment: Sorry if i'm wrong but I have re-read all answers and there is nothing about that..you should have misread.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual Studio (2015, in my case) to create an ASP.NET Webforms Web Application,  with Bootstrap theming, by default the glyphicons are stored in the /fonts folder off the project root.

If you start rearranging your bootstrap files under /Content into subfolders (to support multiple themes, for example), all the references within bootstrap to `../fonts/` will break.  You can either move the fonts folder to the appropriate relative path under `/Content`, or else rename all the references from `../fonts` to `/fonts`.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for these files in my harddisk

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg

glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

then copied them in font file in my .net project

Answer (score 0):

Download full/Non customized package from there site and replace your fonts file with non customized packages fonts. Its will fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create some rewrite conditions to allow them:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^.+\.ttf)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^.+\.eot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^.+\.svg)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^.+\.woff)
```

Answer (score 0):

I work **with VS2015, ASP.NET MVC 6 (RC)** and also had problems (error messages to the reference, icons not showed) with the gliphicons in production (where it has worked in VS (development)).
The reason seems to be, that the MS cdn page is down (at least right now and from Switzerland): 
http://www.websitedown.info/ajax.aspnetcdn.com

Therefore (as temporary workaround), I have changed the external reference in _Layout.cshtml (under environment names="Staging,Production") to "internal" reference:
from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

After doing that, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, `CSS` was fine and there was no issue. 
It also had all the fonts included.

But the problem got resolved only after I installed the "`glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`" I started getting icons properly on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Angular2 and SCSS, as a best practice I copied to my project only the bootstrap files that I'm modifying the other are imported from **node_modules**.. the only problem was with Glyphicons.
After many tries I found that the best solution to me is to copy the font files to my project and set directly this path to **$ icon-font-path** as shown in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue.
Being a total noob at bootstrap, it turned out i was missing the **glyphicon** keyword before the icon name.

```
<span class="glyphicon-search"></span>
```

Should have been

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDN, please make sure you are using the CDN link for the latest version. I was using the CDN link for the previous version and was trying to add newer icons that I found on the website (which contains icons for the latest version) and hence it was not displayed on the web page. Changing cdn link to the latest version might help.

Answer (score -2):

The problem I was facing involved Mac/PC conversion. I received a template from our MAc developers that had images, fonts, glyphicons and everything else you can think of. The problem can be seen when you load the files on to a PC. The filenames will be green by default. This means that they will not work. You will get raw HTML with broken links.

Here's the quick fix. Zip all of the files you received, and extract them into a different folder. All file names will now be black and will work perfectly.

Good luck.

Comment: Same issue here and with other such 'green' files obtained from within the zip file. If you view the properties of the file and look in the advanced attributes make sure the 'Encrypt contents to secure data' check box is cleared. Ok the changes and try again.

Answer (score -2):

It's looks like an UTF char problem in your css. Just update your bootstrap css file with the [new one](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css).

Answer (score -6):

If you for example want the icon of glyphicon-chevron-left

Try adding `class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"`