# bootstrap component not working in asp

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing the following code which is present [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) in my aspx page. But I am not getting the output(i.e., I want to use glyph icons to my button). Can you please help me out.
actual code in site:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
```

I have implemented that in my aspx page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the path of you css file. [Your code is fine](http://bootply.com/95297)

Comment: remaining all button css are working but this glyphicon is not working

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working can help you...