# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicon errors

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I realize there are similar questions that have been answered here, but many of those answers are using gems or modifying Bootstrap's files directly. While those are valid configurations, I want to increase my knowledge set in this area (Sprockets, Rails Pipeline, front-end development in general) and want to understand why this isn't working, what the underlying problem is.

Ruby 2.0.0-p353, Rails 4.0.2, Bootstrap 3.0.3, Nginx 1.4.4, Passenger 4.0.33

I downloaded the latest Bootstrap zip from their site, performed all of the operations found [here](http://rvg.me/2013/11/using-bootstrap-3-with-rails-4/) to included those files directly into my application, and am able to get the glyphicons to show up exactly as expected in my development environment. However, when I deploy to production, the glyphicons show up as squares in Chrome. I added the individual file extensions for the glyphicons files to the production precompile and verified they're showing up in my public/assets folder. The only difference between the js/css files and the glyphicon files is that there's no gzipped file alongside the glyphicon files.

**production.rb:**

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.eot', '*.svg', '*.ttf', '*.woff']
```

I know that Rails loads assets differently between development and production, but why isn't it seeing or understanding the glyphicon assets in production? Is there a way to fix this with my current configuration, or do I need to change the way I'm including these assets in a way to allow me to fix this error?

Also, in both development and production I get the following errors every time I render a page that uses a glyphicon, but the icons still show up. Is this related?

- ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
  "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff")
- ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
  "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf")
- ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
  "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg")

Comment: +1 cant get it working

Comment: `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` before `@import "bootstrap"` helped me, though I don't know the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should manually download the **glyphicons**  **fonts** manually from the site
and put it inside your **app/assets/stylesheets/fonts** folder.

There is some problem which is not yet fixed by `bootstrap` `gem`

You can refer the following link

[Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

1. In `config/application.rb`, add the following after `class Application < Rails::Application`. It should look like this:

   ```
   class Application < Rails::Application
       config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
   ```
2. In the terminal, compile your assets by running:

   ```
   rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
   ```
3. Edit the `bootstrap.css` file by changing `@font-face` resource locations from `../fonts/` to `/assets/`. It should look like this:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
       src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
       src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
   }
   ```

You're done. Just restart with `rails s` and the glyphicons should appear.