# Using Bootstrap 3.1.1 Glyphicons - Firefox is only displaying a weird icon that looks like forks?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Using Bootstrap 3.1.1 Glyphicons - Firefox is only displaying a weird icon that looks like forks?

I'm simply giving a span the class of:

class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"

[image]

So, heck if I know what to do :( Looks great in Chrome!

Comment: can you share the test site link ?

Comment: @LokeshSuthar Sure thing. http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/

Ignore the banners lol. Haven't gotten around to that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug from bootstrap, im not sure where yet but it gets fixed if you use an unminified version of bootstrap.css.

Anyway it seems to be fixed at the latest version:

[Bootstrap.min.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like fonts are not getting loaded properly. I found this **[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working)**. Be sure to read the comments.