# IIS not loading Glypicons icons .woff mime type

Tags: iis, mime-types, glyphicons

IIS refuses to serve bootstrap's glypicons, but happily serves font-awesome icons... what gives?

I have the following in web.config:

```
<staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
```

I've tried x-woff as well as x-font-woff as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640975/1267778)

But it still serves as text/html.. and yet serves font-awesome .woff correctly

[image]

Comment: The difference between the two is your requesting the glyphicons file from Javascript - initiator is jQuery ajax. From this, I gotta assume that Accept in the request header isn't set to application/x-woff.

Comment: good observation. What can I try to solve? I'm using angular although I do have jQuery loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax( url: '/path/to/font/file.woff', 
         headers: { Accept: 'application/x-woff', 
                    "Content-Type": 'application/x-woff' }, 
         method: 'GET')
```