# Some bootstrap glyphicons not loading

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sass, glyphicons, bootstrap-sass

I have a WordPress theme that I'm building with Bootstrap Sass source. The styles are working, but most of the glyphicons aren't (only asterisk and plus). I'm compiling my Bootstrap to the `style.css` and relative to that, there is a folder called `fonts` which holds the glyphicons (I set the `$icon-font-path: "fonts/";`) Here is a snippet from my compiled `style.css` to show that the fonts path is correct:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'; src: url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"); src: url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg"); }
.glyphicon { position: relative; top: 1px; display: inline-block; font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }
```

For e.g, these work:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

But these don't:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Here's a snippet of the glyphicon classes:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:before { content: "\2a"; }
.glyphicon-plus:before { content: "\2b"; }  
.glyphicon-star:before { content: \e006; }
.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before { content: \e125; }
```

I checked the network tab to see if it was loading the glyphicon fonts, and they only appear when the glyphicons work (asterisk, plus). Otherwise, the font file isn't even shown in the network tab (not even a `404`).

Comment: I remember some time ago the bootstrap compiler was creating invalid font files. At that time the icons either showed the wrong icon or left just a little square to indicate an unknown character. Do you see the square when you use icons that don't work? EDIT: Here's a link to an answer that shows what I was talking about - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18474869/2375493

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that the content values were not wrapped in quotes. This is still an issue with the [www.getbootstrap.com](http://www.getbootstrap.com) sass source download, but was [recently fixed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/commit/443d5b49eac84aec1cb2f8ea173554327bfc8c14) in the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) github repo.