# Some Glyphicons not working with bootstrap-sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-sass

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267666/some-bootstrap-glyphicons-not-loading) there as a problem with some glyphicons not working but the problem was fixed in bootstrap-sass. But I am using bootstrap-sass 3.3.5 and some are still not working. For instance these work

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

and these do not work

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

In my `application.css.scss` file I am loading bootstrap-sprockets before bootstrap, i.e.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

I am using `rails 4.2.2`, `sass-rails', '~> 4.0.4'`, `'sprockets-rails', '>=2.1.4'`. Why is this not working?

Here is the relevant excerpt from the assets when I inspect the element chrome web tools:

```
/* line 24, /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@golf_mentor/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss */
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

/* line 37, /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@golf_mentor/gems/bootstrap-sass-  3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss */
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
  content: "\2a";
}

/* line 38, /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@golf_mentor/gems/bootstrap-sass-    3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss */
.glyphicon-plus:before {
  content: "\2b";
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a demo of the code? Codepen will work good.

Comment: It is a ruby on rails application, so it is difficult to demo that section of the code, and it is not yet deployed. The relevant html is the four line aboves, two of which give the correct symbol and two give a square. I do not think my styling that impacts on this as it seems to be exactly the same problem as the post cited above. I am using the bootstrap-sass gem. I have described the relevant section of the application.css.scss file. Is there anything else that you would like to know?

Comment: Did you precompile the assets?

Comment: I am working in development and am not precompiling. I do however have ```config.assets.debug = false```.

Comment: It works for me, and my gemfile shows `bootstrap-sass (3.3.4.1)` Did you do an update recently and you might have old precompiled bootstrap assets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading everything I could think of. The configuration that finally worked was

```
gem 'sprockets-rails', '>=2.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
```

Not sure which did it, but I was very pleased to see those glyphicons.

Answer (score 6):

I succeeded to include glyphicons.
Add the following font-face after included bootstrap.

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

@font-face{
  font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
  src: image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"),
       image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
       image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg")
}
```

Reference:
http://doruby.kbmj.com/taka/20140726/_Rails4_Bootstrap_assets_precompile_glyphicon_

Comment: This leads to a delay between page load and display of icons. And I suggest using `font-url` instead of `image-url`.

Answer (score 2):

In your application.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

(be sure to first import bootstrap-sprockets)

(Found via https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/653#issuecomment-47933937)

Comment: $icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

Answer (score 1):

Try to recompile assets with `rake assets:precompile`. If you are not in development mode, don't forget to add your environment `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I have now tried ```rake assets:precompile``` from the command line. It did not fix the problem. It is occurring in development mode.

Comment: Did you also try to set `config.assets.debug` to true temporarily ?

Comment: I have tried this and it did not work. Also, please see above, where I have added the relevant excerpt from the assets.

Comment: Did you try a different browser ? Maybe you have some Google Chrome plugin messing up with the cache ?

Comment: Can you try to manually downgrade to `bootstrap-sass 3.3.4.1` to see if it fixes anything ? It may be a bug introduced in that version you're using. I also use `sass-rails 5.0.3` but I don't think it's a problem if you use a different version.