# glyphicon not working in mobile browser

Tags: html

I have a problem displaying my shopping cart in a browser on mobile devices. 
Below is the code:

```
echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart <span class="badge" id="cart-counter">'.$count.'</span>',
        array('controller'=>'carts','action'=>'view'),array('escape'=>false));
```

hard-coded in html:

```
 <?php echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><a href="https://sample.com/carts/view">Cart</a><span class="badge" id="cart-counter">'.$count.'</span>'; ?>
```

On a desktop computer, it looks like this (and is clickable):
(Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post a picture here -- Argh!!-- so: it looks like an actual shopping cart with the number of items next to it)

On a mobile device it shows up as a sort of list symbol which is not clickable.

Anybody has encountered that problem? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a hard code your link, without using cakephp syntax to check if you have the same issue?

Comment: It looks like it might be a bootstrap.css issue. Doing some research on that currently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working

Comment: Just show what the end result is.  How it's created isn't the problem - it's what the HTML ends up being.

Comment: I hard-coded it in (without the cakephp structure) - same problem.

Comment: But .. just placed it outside of all the css navigation bar styles and it does show up correctly now. I guess that means something in my css is messing with the cart display.

Comment: if you hard coded it with same problem, change the tags on your question to 'html', and then actually post the html.  Or, if your privileges don't allow, just close this one and start a new question.