# GET error Glyphicon-halflings-regular.ttf/woff/woff2 with custom Twitter Bootstrap theme from Lavish

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap V3.3.4 and [this](http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&image_url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.artinfo.com%2Flacmonfire%2Ffiles%2F2012%2F12%2FWoodruff.jpg&commit=Go%20Lavish) generated theme.  Without the theme, the page loads fine, but when I link to the new theme (below the bootstrap link) the background color changes and the text color changes, but the divs and nav don't change color and I get errors for importing the TTF, WOFF and WOFF2 glyphicon packs.  i've also tried manually linking to those above bootstrap to no avail. Thanks!

[image: The GET issue i've been having shown in the Chrome Console]

```
<head>
<title>Leonardo in Italy</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/subPages.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lavish-bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="subPagesController">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navCollapseHeader">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navCollapseHeader">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="{{ subPages[0].link }}" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ subPages[0].name }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ subPages[1].link }}" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ subPages[1].name }}</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Exploring Leonardo<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="AIS.html">Artist, Inventor, Scientist</a></li>
                        <li><a href="exploring.html">Leo's Projects</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the CSS there is going to be one IMPORT.. something like this

```
@import "../fonts/fontello/css/fontello.css";
```

Or something like this

```
src: url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
```

This lines are trying to get the following on your website.
make sure to have these files in the correspondent folder

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem

I fixed it adding the MIME type on IIS:

```
 .woff  application/x-woff
```

I used this answer for [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640975/3243201)