# gulp concat JS libraries CSS

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-concat

I am using gulp concat to combine all JavaScript libraries CSS file into one. My gulp task looks something like this:

```
gulp.task('concatcss', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/libs/**/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss("all.css").on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(minifyCss().on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

It does work to combine all CSS into one. However, the problem is as the path is changed, any CSS linked file such as `url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff")` will fail to load.

How can I overcome the issue? Is there anyway for it to automatically change the path based on the new output CSS file location?

Comment: check concatcss configuration

Answer (score 2):

You need to set concatcss options `rebaseUrls` to false, its true by default

`rebaseUrls: (default true) Adjust any relative URL to the location of the target file.`

Example:

`concatCss(targetFile, {rebaseUrls:false})`

In your own case:

```
gulp.task('concatcss', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/libs/**/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss("all.css", {rebaseUrls:false}).on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(minifyCss().on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Other Options (since 2.1.0)

```
inlineImports: (default true) Inline any local import statement found
rebaseUrls: (default true) Adjust any relative URL to the location of the target file.
includePaths: (default []) Include additional paths when inlining imports
```

**NB:** 
for a proper import inlining and url rebase, make sure you set the proper base for the input files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried, but it doesn't seems solving the issue. The url still showing the same `url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff")`, which is wrong path from concat css file.

Comment: is this the url in the css before concat? `../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` ? in your web root do you have example index.html, /fonts - directory ? does the `fonts` folder exists in your project root?

Comment: Yes, `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` is in the css before concat. Actually that one is from bootstrap.min.css. Before concat, I was able to load the icon. After concat, it fail to load.

Comment: please see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-are-not-working, you might need to move the `fonts` folder

Comment: The path is correct from the original bootstrap css file and I have no problem loading it before I concat all css files into one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the base option to gulp.src like this: `{ base: 'dist' }`

Your code reworked:

```
gulp.task('concatcss', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/libs/**/*.css', { base: 'dist'})
    .pipe(concatCss("all.css").on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(minifyCss().on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: and of course for this to work leave rebaseUrls true, which is the default.