# re-adding glyphicons back to bootstrap 4.0

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

Hi I use a theme of bootstrap known as [minton](http://coderthemes.com/minton/dark-dark/icons-materialdesign.html) which handles icons moslty using font awesome. I think it is a bootstrap 3/4 thing.

In short: [This boostrap 4.0 lacks glypicons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-are-not-working). I would like to add them. Too many dependencies require them. I have the glyphicons fonts in the fonts dir

- `asssets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`
- `asssets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg`
- `asssets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.tff`
- `asssets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`

and the bootstrap.min.css is here
 - `asssets/css/bootstrap.min.css`

and I added this css to the page via a icons.css (which among other things) now has

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

but they are not appearing when requested. Can anyone shed light onto this?

Comment: Can you be more clear about whether you need font awesome or glyphicons? They are separate products

Comment: `This boostrap 4.0 lacks glypicons. I would like to add them` I use https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php which relies on glyphicons

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 no longer has glyphicons, so if you use boostrap 4, another solution will need to be found (eg. font-awesome)

You have mentioned the date picker library, that library supports bootstrap 2 and 3 and it mentions that its being depreciated in favour of this one: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

You best bet is to replace that component rather than trying to retrofit parts of some older library to make another old library work which will eventually need replacing. You might as well relate it sooner rather than later. Work needs to be done regardless , it might as we be somewhat future-proof.

Comment: that other datetimepicker does not function (it refuses to show) on minton. I have spent 2 days on this. As an side, could you please not second guess a question. Answering a question with a OP "this is a bad question" is not the correct way to behave.

Comment: my point was more about finding another solution more than the one that was mentioned. What JS library are you using?

Comment: minton uses `datepicker `and `daterangepicker` and deliberately (I think) missed datetimepicker from it's Forms-> Advanced page  http://coderthemes.com/minton/dark-dark/form-advanced.html

Comment: if you go to http://coderthemes.com/minton/dark-dark/form-elements.html you will also see they aren't using it there either. I have worked out after using 4 librarys (three of which are called `boostrap-datetimepicker` but have *nothing* whatsoever in common with one another, one of which was ancient, hideous but at least worked) that the easiest thing is to use a library that will work but the only issue is the glyphicons. it should be trivial to add them

Comment: interestingly `eonasdan`'s project has worse i18n, much less features, the markup is massively inconsistent depending on what page you're on, it doesn't illustrate `format` at all ( I found it it uses `moment` for the date formatting but it doesn't `say` so), and, it does't have a working example of date only mechanic (the example  doesn't work at least) and isn't bootstrap 4 and is *also* dependent on using glyphicons