# Php echo base_url failed to load css

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, codeigniter-3

I want to load awesome.css in my php file. I have a code like this in my php :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('resources/web2/lib/css/awesome.css'); ?>"/>
```

But when I check the awesome.css file, there is a code which have link to another url :

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../resources/web2/lib/font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfontf77b.eot?v=3.2.1');src:url('../font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfontd41d.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfontf77b.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'),url('../font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfontf77b.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'),url('../font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
```

And when I load the page in web browser there is an error like this :

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://[::1]/yisc/resources/web2/lib/font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfontf77b.eot?v=3.2.1`

Please kindly help me to solved this issue, I really don't understand what happens here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloadable font on firefox: bad URI or cross-site access not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024333/downloadable-font-on-firefox-bad-uri-or-cross-site-access-not-allowed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `config.php` and set the baseurl

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
```

Its better to take look at [Codeigniter Documentation about Base Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url)

---

`src:url('../font/` depends on the folders you are being.  Check [Path (computing) in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))

Comment: I left the config for the base url blank : $config['base_url'] = ''; since it is stated that "If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain and path to your installation

Comment: @WhiteMaskGuy Its wrong Buddy. You have to set base Url

Comment: Hi, i updated the config like you suggest, but i still got the error message : `downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://localhost/yisc/resources/web2/lib/font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfontf77b.eot?v=3.2.1`

Comment: @WhiteMaskGuy      This is a case of Experience over Theories. Try setting the base_url as suggested and see what happens. Chances are that whether it works or not; it is just worth trying out (if only to confirm that it is relevant, at the least).

Comment: remove these `?v=3.2.1`  and check path is active `resources/web2/lib/‌​font/FontAwesome/font‌​awesome-webfontf77b.e‌​ot`

Comment: @Poiz Ok, Sorry. But I already add it, but it still show me the same error message, not exactly the same though.

Comment: @WhiteMaskGuy as i know your font awesome is wrong. check this link https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts

Comment: @Spartan I got this error message `downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://localhost/yisc/resources/web2/lib/font/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfontf77b.eot?v=3.2.1`

Comment: @Spartan I'll try to download the font file on the link that you provide and update the status after that. Wait a moment.

Comment: @WhiteMaskGuy load CDN style too `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: @Spartan Hi, spartan, there is 2 file .eot which loaded in the css file, fontawesome-webfontf77b.eot and fontawesome-webfontd41d.eot , do i have to change both of it with the same eot file in the download link ? fontawesome-webfont.eot , i actually take a random html template from internet and try to apply it in codeigniter.

Comment: @WhiteMaskGuy i ner heard of name like that in font awesome. reomve those and check. think no problem with it

Comment: @WhiteMaskGuy happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you actually have in your real code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
         href="<?phpechobase_url('resources/web2/lib/css/awesome.css'); ?>"/>`
```

Something is not quite OK.... the `echo` Part seems to form one word with `base_url`

You may consider putting a space between `echo` and `base_url()` instead:

```
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" 
         href = "<?php echo base_url('resources/web2/lib/css/awesome.css'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: No, it's typo actually, i dont forgot the space between it. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

i have same this problem
just go to Application floder and go to config after that choose **autoload.php**

In this autoload.php page search about `($autoload['helper']) = array()` you should replace to `($autoload['helper']) = array('url');`