# Font-awesome icons are missing

Tags: css, html, fonts

I want to design a website using html5 and bootstrap.In, and to my html code, I need Font-Awesome icons. But when I put `font-awesome.min.css` and corresponding fonts, the Font-Awesome icons did not load in my page.

So when I inspect that page, I get the following errors and warning on my console:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Roboto" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://[::1]/futuroit/userasset/css/Fonts/Roboto/regular.ttf  style.css:9:1
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Roboto" style:normal weight:300 stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://[::1]/futuroit/userasset/css/Fonts/Roboto/roboto-light.ttf  style.css:46:1

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://[::1]/futuroit/userasset/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0  font-awesome.min.css:4:14
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Open Sans" style:normal weight:bold stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://[::1]/futuroit/userasset/css/Fonts/Open%20Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what is `[::1]` in your url?

Comment: Try it without the IPv6 address in there. And also, can you post the source CSS where you reference the fonts?

Comment: @noobcode      localhost/futuroit

Answer (score 0):

Either address is wrong (or) configuration setting is missing

1. verify your address by checking it directly on the browser or simply put the source and refer the path.
2. refer this [Downloadable font on firefox: bad URI or cross-site access not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024333/downloadable-font-on-firefox-bad-uri-or-cross-site-access-not-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

try to include **font-awesome.css** plugin not **font-awesome.min.css** because some time it shows error.
When you are including this plugin in your html file include it above of all script files some time it also create a problem.

Comment: ok have you included class name like this in file <i class="fa fa-plus""></i>

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure correct format is used with the fonts.**

For me the Firefox gave error:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "opensans-semibold" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1) source: <path-to-font>/OpenSans-SemiBold.svg
```

Upon checking the file the **format** provided in `format()` for `svg` was incorrect:

```
url("../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-regular/OpenSans-Regular.svg") format("woff2");
```

So the format **woff2** was provided for **svg** font which I corrected to:

```
url("../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-regular/OpenSans-Regular.svg") format("svg");
```

And the problem was gone!

Answer (score 0):

Either address is wrong (or) configuration setting is missing
verify your address by checking it directly on the browser or simply put the source and refer the path.
refer this Downloadable font on firefox: bad URI or cross-site access not allowed

Answer (score -1):

if you just add this line of code

```
  <link href="fonts/fontawesome/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

inside of your page you just need go to the all.min.css and you can see there are some urls for fonts that you must inculde in your directory of your site.